# How to move a file to another drive via drag & drop without pressing Cmd

Tags: keyboard, finder

How can I configure macOS' Finder in a way that I can **move** (not copy) **files** via drag & drop to another drive **without pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>**?

I'm transferring files to a network storage on a regular basis and pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd> all the time is a bit tedious.

Comment: dupe: https://superuser.com/questions/323976/how-to-change-default-drag-and-drop-behavior-on-os-x

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible when using drag and drop between drives as of macOS 10.12.x Sierra.

There is also no known method to change this behavior.

---

**Alternative**

Instead you may use these keyboard shortcuts:

- <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to copy the items in Finder
- <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to move the items without copying.

Comment: So much better! I'm on my macbook and I was doing a contiguous dragged out selection of items in list view in a folder in finder, released the mouse, went back and held CMD and proceeded to click the selection to drag it to another folder. Instead CMD wound up just deselecting a few elements from the selection. Maybe I was off on something, completely frustrating.